# How to change intermediate event type in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect, bpmn

Is there a way how to change the event type for an existing [intermediate event](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/model_bpel2_intermediate_event.html)? When I do a mistake, I have to delete the event and create new event.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, however you can't use the docked properties window.

You have to open the properties **dialog** (select element and press Alt-Enter)
[image]